# exercise: split the array values into positive and negative arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

i've had a hard time thinking how to fix this out
i need to split the negative values and the positive values but when i launched the program the results was wrong im just so new to programming especially in arrays so any help will appreciate.

here is the exercise problem:
a)define an array with a maxinum of 20 integers values and fill the array with numbers of your own choosing as intializers then write, compile, and run a c++ program that reads the numbers in the array and places all zero and positve numbers in  an array named positive and all negative numbers in an array named negative finally, have your program display the values in both the positive and negative arrays

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int MAXVAL = 5; // created 5 values for num, pos, neg i set to 5 because for testing purposes

int num[MAXVAL]; 
int pos[MAXVAL];
int neg[MAXVAL];

int i, k, c, c2, j;

c = 0;
c2 = 0;

cout << "enter the numbers: " << endl;

for(i = 0; i < MAXVAL; i++) // inputs the users
{
    cin >> num[i];
}

for(i = 0, k = 0; i < MAXVAL; i++){ // this function finds the positivevalue
    if(num[k] > -1){
        pos[k] = num[k];
        k++;
        c = c + 1;
    }
    else{
        pos[k] = pos[k];
        k++;
    }
}

for(i = 0, j = 0; i < MAXVAL; i++){ // this function finds the negative        value
    if(num[j] < 0){
        neg[j] = num[j];
        j++;
        c2 = c2 + 1;
    }
    else{
        neg[j] = neg[j];
        j++;
    }
}

cout << "the positive numbers is: " << endl;////// displays the result

for(i = 0; i < c; i++){
    cout << " " << pos[i];
}

cout << "\nthe negative numbers is: " << endl;

for(i = 0; i < c2; i++){
    cout << " " << neg[i];
}

return 0;
```

}

the output was just like this:

enter a number : 1, -5 , 4, -55, 5

the positive numbers is: 1 8 4

the negative numbers is: 4286352 -5

Comment: You should have `int i, k, c, c2, j;` initialized with some values.

Comment: but i initialized the variables in the loop and in the conditional statements

Comment: Instead of declaring a bunch of misc variables at the beginning, try to declare them as close as possible to first use. For example, `for (int i = 0; ..)` is better. It's ok to call loop variables a single letter, but other variables should be well-named or a comment describing them. For example, what is `c` for? It's not easy to tell.

Comment: @KrysselTillada _"but i initialized the variables"_ No `k` is never initialized properly, and `pos[k] = pos[k];` is also wrong, since `pos[k]` never was initialized also (it's a completely nonsensical operation BTW).

Comment: `pos[k] = pos[k];` is no-op and can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there is already standard function `std::partition_copy` declared in header `<algorithm>` that is able to do the job. Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    const size_t MAX_VAL = 5;
    int num[MAX_VAL] = { 1, -5 , 4, -55, 5 };
    int pos[MAX_VAL];
    int neg[MAX_VAL];

    for ( int x : num ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto p = std::partition_copy( std::begin( num ), std::end( num ),
                                  std::begin( pos ), std::begin( neg ),
                                  []( int x ) { return !( x < 0 ); } );

    for ( int *first = pos; first != p.first; ++first ) std::cout << *first << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int *first = neg; first != p.second; ++first ) std::cout << *first << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -5 4 -55 5 
1 4 5 
-5 -55
```

If you want to write the program yourself without using standard algorithms then the approach can look like

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t MAX_VAL = 5;
    int num[MAX_VAL] = { 1, -5 , 4, -55, 5 };
    int pos[MAX_VAL];
    int neg[MAX_VAL];

    for ( int x : num ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;


    size_t n1 = 0, n2 = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_VAL; i++ )
    {
        if ( !( num[i] < 0 ) )
        {
            pos[n1++] = num[i];
        }
        else
        {
            neg[n2++] = num[i];
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++ ) std::cout << pos[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++ ) std::cout << neg[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as above.

Of course you may change the program such a way that the user will enter values of the original array himself.

Comment: i try your second code error comes it says range based for loops are not allowed in c++98 mode in line 10

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada Replace the range based for loop with an ordinary loop
for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_VAL; i++ ) std::cout << num[i] << ' ';

Comment: ohh thanks it works but what this size_t stands for and this statement ( !( num[i] < 0 ) )  do

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada size_t is a typedef for some unsigned integer type usually it is unsigned long.. There is no greate sense that indices of an array would be declared with some signed integer type. As for condition  !( num[i] < 0 )  then it is equivalent to num[i] >= 0.

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada By the way for such simple exercises you can use online compiler at www.ideone.com . You may select C++ 14 compiler. In this case the range based for statement will be compiled.

Comment: thanks im gonna try that im using a compiler called gnu gcc i dont know if its a good compiler because its pre installed in codeblocks by the way im just reading a book that my dad bought it so i cant understand the 1st code you write but your second code works for me with a little explanations : )

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada C++ is an extensive language. Apart from the syntax there is also the standard library including standard algorithms.

Comment: Ohh thats why someday I get there and understand. The standard library uses but for now I'm following the book from start to end

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada What is the title of the book?

Comment: a first book of c++ gary j bronson

Answer (score 0):

You're initailising uninitialised elements with themselves.  This is your problem, initialise them with a sentinal value like `0`:

```
pos[k] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When looping to find positive and negative, you should use the loop index for comparison and then store in the second index like so:

```
if(num[i] > -1){
    pos[k] = num[i];
    k++;
    c = c + 1;
}
```

which compares the `ith` element to -1 and then store it at `kth` index in pos array and

```
if(num[i] < 0){
    neg[j] = num[i];
    j++;
    c2 = c2 + 1;
}
```

You also need to remove the else clause otherwise you might write after max index `c` and `c2` and also because `pos[k] = pos[k]` is wrong.

Comment: i removed the else statement and this is the output  enter numbers: xxxx  the positive number is: 1          the negative number is:       the 4 other numbers is missing i dont know why

Comment: Did you just remove the else statement or did you fix the index variables as well?

Comment: i just remove the else statement i didnt change the variables

Comment: compare the ith element to -1 and then store it a kth index in pos array can you explain so i can understand thanks

Comment: I was just explaining the code snippet with word. I moved it close to the code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

if this is c++, please don't use c-style arrays. 
a solution with `vector` might look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    vector<int> num, pos, neg;

    cout << "enter count :";
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << "enter number :" ;
        int val;
        cin >> val;
        num.push_back(val);
    }

    for( auto val : num )
    {
        if( val >= 0 )
            pos.push_back(val);
        else
            neg.push_back(val);
    }

    cout << "the positive numbers are: " << endl;
    for( auto val : pos )
        cout << " " << val;

    cout << "\nthe negative numbers are: " << endl;
    for( auto val : neg )
        cout << " " << val;
}
```

a few notes on how `vector` works

```
// this creates a empty vector of int's, named v;
vector<int> v;

// this adds one element (in this case 3) last to the vector 
v.push_back(3);

// this gets the current number of elements
int n = v.size();

// this retrieves the first element of the vector
int a = v[0]; // zero based index

// this is a range based for loop, that prints every element
for( auto elem : v )
    cout << elem << " " ;

// that could also be done with a regular for loop
for( int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i )
    cout << v[i] << " ";

// this makes the vector empty
v.clear();
```

Comment: well this code works too but im not into vectors so i cant understand how it works thanks phew trying to get used to arrays its so confusing